# Remove card background for a cardVie on top Android

Tags: android, radio-button, android-cardview

I want to get this as a result.[image: Im trying to achieve this.] But What I'm getting is [image: This]this. Here is the code below which I have tried. I Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bankToggle"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="52dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/netbankingCard"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
            style="@style/carViewQuickInvestRadio"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/netBankingrbrl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relContainRadThisMonth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/netbankingRB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:checked="false"
                app:buttonTint="@color/color_green" />

            <com.goalwise.customViews.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/color_fab_text"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/netbankingRB"
                android:text="@string/netbanking"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_regular_text_size"
                app:font="@string/gotham_font" />
        </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnlContainRadThisMonth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relContainRadThisMonth"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relContainRadThisMonth"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relContainRadThisMonth"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relContainRadThisMonth"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/nachrbcard"
            style="@style/carViewQuickInvestRadio"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/nachrbrl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relContainRadNach"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/nachRB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:checked="false"
                app:buttonTint="@color/color_green" />

            <com.goalwise.customViews.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/color_fab_text"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nachRB"
                android:text="@string/nach"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_regular_text_size"
                app:font="@string/gotham_font" />
        </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnlContainRadNach"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relContainRadNach"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relContainRadNach"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relContainRadNach"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relContainRadNach"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RadioGroup>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_toggle"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardNbNach"
                android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
                style="@style/carViewQuickInvestRadio.bg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.goalwise.customViews.CustomTextView
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/netBanking_both"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="1.3dp"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/styleTextViewDisc"
                    android:text="@string/quick_net_both"
                    />
                <com.goalwise.customViews.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/guarenteeTag"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                    android:text="@string/secure_transaction"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    style="@style/styleTextViewQuickDisc.noPadding"

                    />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </FrameLayout>


    </FrameLayout>
```

The above code is giving me the results shown. Im trying to remove the border on top of card view by giving -ve margin. which did not help to solve the problem. Please help.

Comment: use this property in cardview           card_view:cardElevation="0dp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: This is how it looks!]

You can do something like this. It may not be the proper way. But it gives you almost the same result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/radioOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/splitter"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/splitter"
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/radioTwo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/splitter"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#f7f7f7"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    />
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/rootTwo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioOne"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    />
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/patchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioOne"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/splitter"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    />
```

Make sure that all your card views are in the same parent and it has same elevation. Shadow becomes visible when you give corner radius. So to hide that shadow I'm applying a patch on top of that. You can clearly see how I did it in the xml.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardNbNach"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/relContainRadThisMonth"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/netbankingRB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:checked="false"
                app:buttonTint="@color/grey" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/netbankingRB"
                android:text="Net Banking"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/netbanking_bottomline"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/grey"
                   />
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/relContainRadNach"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/nachRB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:checked="false"
                app:buttonTint="@color/grey" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nachRB"
                android:text="NACH"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/nach_bottom_line"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/grey"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/netBanking_both"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="1.3dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/guarenteeTag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"


        />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You can simply use single card and when click on NetBanking you need to gone the Visibility of the view(netbanking_bottomline) and when click on NACH , you need to gone the view(nach_bottom_line).

this may be a simple steps to hide the bottom line of clicking item rather than setting negative margins to the card.